# How to display external API Oauth Dialog for Google Sheets AddOn

Tags: api, oauth, google-apps-script, oauth-2.0

I'm playing around with building an app to integrate a 3rd party API into google sheets using app script and the new AddOn API's for google docs. I've got the Oauth2.0 flow working by adapting this code [here](https://gist.github.com/entaq/4079885). This works, but I don't want this app to be a standalone web app - I just want to add another menu with a few select functions - one of which will be authenticate to the spreadsheet. I have this working in parts (1. new menu with authenticate button that runs a function when clicked. 2. Url that starts Oauth process when I hit that specific URL in a another window), I just am not sure how to connect them.

My problem is that I'm not sure how to display the 3rd party API's Oauth dialog in a way that is integrated with Google Docs. I've tried loading it into a sidebar, but that doesn't seem to be working. Is there a way to open a 3rd party Oauth2.0 dialog with app script?

This is my first interaction with app script but It'e been pretty easy and painless so far. I'm just wondering what the best way to approach this problem would be.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in way to do a 3rd party OAuth2 flow using Google Apps Script. However it is possible to write an OAuth2 flow on top of Apps Script, and this library is one such implementation:

https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth2